# I want to retrieve data from Firebase into an HTML textbox, then update the data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 questions.

1. I have managed to retrieve data from Firebase into an HTML table but can't understand how to put that data into an HTML form, basically the same form I used to create the data in the first place, make changes and then update data via the form in Firebase.
2. Currently I am retrieving the data using `child_added` into an HTML table, it works fine and shows a new row in the table but when I use `child_changed` it happens that the previous data (row) remains and a new row is created to show the changes. How can I show the changes on the same row it was changed in Firebase?

Thank You

Code to show added data:

```
var registration = firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION");

var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION");

dataRef.on("child_added", function(data) {
    var rData = data.val();
$("#reData").append("<tr><td>" + rData.email + "</td><td>" + rData.name + "</td><td>" + rData.gender + "</td><td>" + rData.birthdate + "</td><td>" + rData.phone + "</td><td>" + rData.state + "</td><td>" + rData.school + "</td><td>" + rData.class + "</td><td>" + rData.classname + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Code to show updated data in HTML form:

```
var upData = firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION");

upData.on("child_changed", function(data) {
    var rData = data.val();
$("#reData").append = ("<tr><td>" + rData.email + "</td><td>" + rData.name + "</td><td>" + rData.gender + "</td><td>" + rData.birthdate + "</td><td>" + rData.phone + "</td><td>" + rData.state + "</td><td>" + rData.school + "</td><td>" + rData.class + "</td><td>" + rData.classname + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: can you show your working example?

Comment: In a screenshot or how ?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle and update this question with the link so i can help you.

Comment: I'm getting errors in fiddle when I run the code : {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x50a7c90>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x5246ad0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x50a7c90>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field':....

Comment: is your data got updated properly with the changes that you made?

Comment: Not via fiddle otherwise it works fine, I can add data from my form to firebase, I can retrieve as well but only into an HTML table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huud Rych, I have created a jsfiddle for you. In the fiddle data will be appended to the table from firebase when clicking on edit, I have used jquery, you can also try it. The data appended to the form. when pressing the update button the data will be updated and the table will get refreshed. [Sample JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1asyx1j/7/)

```
for (var key in data){
           data[key].key=key;// here I am pushing the key from the firebase into the array, so we can use it while updating the data. See in the Js fiddle
           dataArray.push(data[key]);
        };
```

Comment: Sure but it says this : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Oh Ok. When you get fifteen reputations, kindly upvote my answer.

Comment: No Mention. I just shared my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry for troubling again, I edited your code and tried to use it for my case, it works fine but doesnt update as it shows error in console : Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"  firebase.js:324:31719

Comment: upload new question and show me the problem. I will help you. I have faced these errors before

Comment: Thanks, uploaded here : https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17389723 / html and js file uploaded here : http://www114.zippyshare.com/v/NHES6Zyf/file.html